# KDE4: Wallpaper blending an image and a color

Tags: kde, desktop-customization, kde-4

I am one of those KDE 3 die hards.

With KDE 3 I was able to set my wallpaper to an image, and then to add a solid color (with some alpha value) on top of it. I find it makes the background interesting but not destructing.

I can't find this feature in KDE 4, however.

Is it missing all together, or did the KDE devs just moved it to someplace I can't find?

Answer (score 1):

(answering myself)

The best thing I found so far is the [Day and Night Wallpaper](http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php?content=118636) over at [KDE-Look.org](http://kde-apps.org/). It does not do what I need it to do, but it should be relatively simple to adapt the [code](http://www.gitorious.org/pdamsten/plasmoids/trees/master/day-and-night) for my needs.

I will update this post if and when I find the time to do this work, or if I will find a better answer.